# iOS Archive released to iTunes does not work the same as the project

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an issue that has me completely perplexed. I built a simple openGL game in iOS ( 4.2.1 xCode ) and tested it on my device and all was fine.

I then archived it and submitted it to Apple. They approved and released it.

When I download it ( onto the same device ) or anyone else does ( onto variety of the latest devices ) much of the game play is missing. Its as if the archive did not capture all the settings from the project.

I can only conclude that at the archive stage something happened to the build.

Does anyone know how i can test run the actual archive on my device ( without submitting it ) so that I can get to the bottom of what is different ?

Thank you very much anyone who reads this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are about to release a game to appstore, you'd better make a distribution AD-HOC build and give the ipa to some friends of yours. Of course, don't forget to mark their devices when making distribution ad-hoc profile. So once you have this .ipa, delete your development build from device and install .ipa via itunes. Then you'll see it the way as it is downloaded for the appstore.
Furthermore, you say that some scenes/resources are missing: this could be for the reason that when you added the resources/files to your projects you did't enable "copy files to project directory" and "add to target" so the build was incomplete.
OKay, once you assured your ad-hoc ipa is working fine, make the same distribution profile, but only for apptore. Build the app and submit to appstore!
Hopefully this will help, bye!

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. I have now created the adhoc distribution profile and have been able to recreate the same issue with the .ipa I distributed that I saw with the actual release. Therefore I am now in a position where I can test the archive until I manage to understand and overcome the issue I had.

Comment: I have now discovered what was wrong with my release. In one of the methods that controlled sprite movement I had calculated the new x and z coordinates and was returning an array containing these via a pointer. The function header was "float * MoveSprites()". Clearly this was fairly poor programming practice and although it was accepted whilst in development ( running on my device ) in the release version it seems this was unacceptable. I have rewritten this function to allow the return values to be passed by reference and now the .ipa works just fine. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when this kind of thing happens it's because something that was included in early dev builds is no longer there, but is still in the binary on the device. (Dev builds are incremental, so some files deleted from or changed in a project can sometimes persist.) You could try the following:

1. Delete the app from your device
2. Delete the derived data folder in the organizer
3. Clean all build targets

This may reveal the problem. It's hard to say without more info about what "much of the gameplay is missing" means.

Comment: Now its interesting you say about the dev builds being incremental because what has been released does bear a resemblence to some very early versions of this app. When I first switched on the z-buffer I had to them make various changes to overcome various depth gremlins and this released version looks a bit like it did then. Thank you for this response - I will work through your list. Maybe I have somehow released a 4 week old version.